# Android: Video View: how to play a video on a loop

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I got a simple dialog box with a `VideoView` in it and I want to play the video in a loop.

I'm currently using a quick fix

```
 //Video Loop
        vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vv.start();
            }
        });
```

but I would like to know if there is a better way?

---

**Edit**

I'm adding more code because I don't know how I can get access to the MediaPlayer object form the `VideoView`:

```
String path = defaultPath+currentVideoRessource;


    if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
        Log.e("extra","File URL/path is empty");
    } else {
        // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
        if (!path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                Uri pathURI = Uri.parse(defaultPath+currentVideoRessource);
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(pathURI);
    }
    current = path;
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MyOnCompletionListener(this));
    //Video Loop
    //              mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    //                  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //                      mVideoView.start(); //need to make transition seamless.
    //                  }
    //              });

    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

I'm currently looking into using directly `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView` bu I would like to know if there is a way with `VideoView` directly

Comment: Please try this, it is work for me clearly

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606389/3414469][1]

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use [setLooping(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29) on your MediaPlayer instance.

--Edit--

How about using [setOnPrepareListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) instead of setOnCompletionListener? This gives you access to the MediaPlayer object.

```
vv.setOnPreparedListener (new OnPreparedListener() {                    
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem I have is I use VideoView and I don't see how to gain access to the media player. (I'll update my code)

Comment: Please see the edited answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: well I actually switch to a surface view and a media player and it solved my problem

Comment: @Jason... So now you use a media player? Is it inline? Can you post some code? I have been doing this with videoviews in a list but scrolling creates some rendering issues. Thanks.

Comment: The above code didn't work for me -- maybe setLooping has no effect on streaming videos?

Comment: @MarcBernstein Bernstein  It adds few seconds pause in looping.How can I play without any pause?

Comment: @MarcBernstein It works for mp4 video(File) but not working with m3u8. Please suggest me a solution if you have any Idea about the m3u8 file.

Comment: Any solutions for video from a URL? Same issue here @SvenViking

Answer (score 5):

You Can take reference form below codes, Where setup_welcome_video is video file.

```
        myVideo = findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.setup_welcome_video);
        myVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
        myVideo.start();
        myVideo.requestFocus();
        myVideo.setOnPreparedListener (mp -> mp.setLooping(true));
```